# Raspberry Pi Matchbox virtual keyboard missing colon

Tags: display

The Matchbox virtual keyboard is missing the colon character. Is there a solution to add this character?

Comment: Have you tried pressing **SHIFT**?

Comment: @lornix hahahahahahahahahaha A+ answer there.

Answer (score 1):

Per lornix's comment below the question, pressing the shift modifier key should change the semicolon to a colon. I'm reasonably sure that this is the relevant code used in the [keyboard-extended.xml](https://github.com/mwilliams03/matchbox-keyboard/blob/master/layouts/keyboard-extended.xml#L253) file which, I think, is the layout you're using at the moment:

```
<key fill='false'>
      <default display=";" />
      <shifted display=":" />
</key>
```

If, for whatever reason, you can't press the shift key and *need* to make a new layout with a colon, there are some instructions provided on [matchbox's Github page](https://github.com/mwilliams03/matchbox-keyboard):

> ## Making your own keyboard layouts
>
> Keyboard layout files are UTF8 XML files ( Make sure they are saved
>   with this encoding! ). They are loaded from the directory
>   $PREFIX/share/matchbox-keyboard and are named in the format
>   keyboard[-locale][-variant].xml. This can be overridden by setting
>   MB_KBD_CONFIG environment variable to a valid config file path or by
>   creating $HOME/.matchbox/keyboard.xml.
>
> The basic layout of the file looks like;
>
> ```
> <keyboard>
>
> <options>
> </options>
>
> <layout>
>   <row>
>     <key ...>       
>       <default .. >     
>       <shifted .. >     
>       <mod1 .. >
>       ....    
>     <key>
>     .... more keys ...    
>     <space width="1000" />
>   </row>
>   <row>
>   ...
>   </row>
> </layout>
>
> </keyboard>
> ```